# How to clear browser cache through command line

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I am getting the error "Error generating workflow content. Try to clear the browser cache and reload page" 
How to clear the chrome cache.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via the command line or terminal. There is a nice tutorial [here](https://www.ostechnix.com/clear-web-browser-cache-commandline-linux/)

On mac you can open Chrome. Open Preferences using `cmd + ,`. Then scroll down and open Advanced. Then click on Clear browsing data and select Cached images and files.

I don't have a Windows machine, but I found a nice guide for clearing cache on Windows [here](https://www.4winkey.com/windows-10/how-to-delete-clear-cookies-and-cache-in-chrome-on-windows-10.html)

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.